# TensorboardX: tensorboard: command not found

Tags: pytorch, tensorboard

so I am attempting to access the tensorboard visualizations from this [project](https://github.com/jcwleo/curiosity-driven-exploration-pytorch). I am not to familiar with the library, but when I try to access the tensorboard during training using the command

```
tensorboard --dir data
```

I get returned with the tensor board command not found. (Running on Ubuntu 18.04). pip list displays that I have tensorboardX 1.9 downloaded, so I am not sure why the command is not being recognized. I have pytorch installed, and I am not aware of any other dependencies that are needed.

Comment: tensorboardX is an interface to tensorboard. You also need to `pip install tensorboard` to your environment which installs the tensorboard tool itself.

Comment: @jodag installing tensorboard did allow me to use the tensorboard command. Unfortunately when running tensorboard --inspect --logdir data , nothing is found.

Answer (score 0):

You can check what is in the [PyTorch Tensorboard documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensorboard.html) together with the installation instructions.

Answer (score 0):

If you use conda, try to install tensorboard outside conda. That helped me.

Also, such a command could work if you have problems with bash command

```
python -m tensorboard.main --logdir=.
```